# in contrast to C code, why C++ code doesn't need "#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L"?

Tags: c++, c, preprocessor

When I use "POSIX interval timer" or do signal handling,
I have to insert

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

on line 1 inside any of my files.
But I figured out that only C code needs it, but not in C++ code.

How does the `g++` compiler work differently from the `gcc` compiler
on this issue?

---

below is my system environment (gcc : same version)

```
 user@~ $ g++ --version
 g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609
 Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
 This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
 There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

and I build the project adding this line in CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -std=c++14 -Wall")
```

Comment: Which version(s) of GCC and G++ are you using (`gcc --version` and `g++ --version`)?  Which command line options are you using to compile with GCC and with G++?  Which platform are you on?  There are all sorts of possibilities, but using `-std=gnu11` vs `-std=c11` might account for the C side, and if you don't specify a standard with G++ (or if you use `-std=gnu++17` instead of `-std=c++17`), that could be the rest of the story.  But without most of the information requested, it's a case of the blind leading the blind.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry for being late, I added my system environment

Comment: Thanks for adding some of the information I requested.  Please could you add the rest too. The request was not made casually.

Comment: Yesterday, while I was trying to build the project without any error, I tried many different ways. 
Today, now I know how I should do it, and I just find that cmake-build OK, but only CLI-build (e.g. g++ -g -std=c++14 -Wall ./include/header_file.h ./src/source_file.cpp) (e.g. g++ -g -std=c11 -Wall ./include/header_file.h ./src/source_file.c) I get the error. I think I was under pressure and my mind was not clear.
<br>
When I build the C code with cmake, then it was also built error-lessly even though I omit the "#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE (sth)".

Comment: <br>
@JonathanLeffler Does this mean cmake also include some kind of define inside its source?

Comment: Programs like `cmake` try to deal with the issues like this in the background so you don't have to deal with them directly. Their configuration process ensures the correct flags are set so that compilation will succeed. That's also the job for AutoConf and family — if you type `./configure`, you're probably using an AutoConf configuration which interrogates the system to find out what's necessary.  I'm puzzled by your use of `g++ -q -std=c11 -Wall ./include/header_file.h ./src/source_file.c` on two counts: (1) you used `g++1 instead of `gcc` with a `.c` file, and (2) you compiled a header.

Comment: I know using gcc for c, g++ for cpp. It was a typo ha ha. Thank you very much for your replies :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i’m a newbie in programming. I have to learn a lot. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

g++ defines _GNU_SOURCE, which defines _POSIX_C_SOURCE.

This is done because it is required by the standard c++ template library.

Fuller discussion at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2082

Description of the macros at https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html

Comment: *Currently* required by the Gnu standard "template" library. But it should not be relied on; someone might fix the bug some say.

Answer (score 2):

Let's do a simple experiment. Try to compile this short source file:

```
auto f()
{
    return _POSIX_C_SOURCE;
}
```

Nope. It doesn't compile since `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is not defined.

But what if we include a C++ header?

```
#include <iostream>

auto f()
{
    return _POSIX_C_SOURCE;
}
```

It compiles well.

(Try it live: https://godbolt.org/z/C6_a6P)

That means it has nothing to do with g++. Somewhere in some of the C++ standard library header files, this macro is defined.

Comment: That's a tad simplistic; the C++ headers are provided by the C++ compiler, G++, rather than by the o/s.  So you're right about it being a library header, but not — in my view of how it works — about it not being a G++ issue.  It would be helpful if the OP provided the information I [requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53037824/in-contrast-to-c-code-why-c-code-doesnt-need-define-posix-c-source-200809#comment92975875_53037824).

Comment: I like this concise example.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Admittedly too simplistic. But in my defence, it is a reproducable empircal result which shows some insight.